# Expression as parameter inside angular on-click method

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jakarta-ee

In following code I need to get ticket id as a method parameter.
**ng-click="rejectTicket({{ticket.id}})"** *(ofcourse this code does not work)*

I want to send that id of specific ticket in generated table row to my back-end java controller and invoke `reject()` method. Any ideas how to reach this functionality "*clean*" way?

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets" ng-show="ticket.state === 'NEW' || ticket.state === 'PROCESSING'">
    <td>{{ticket.created}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="#" ng-click="rejectTicket({{ticket.id}})">
            <img class="ico" src="../lib/images/reject.png" title="Reject ticket"> &nbsp;
        </a>
        <a href="#" ng-hide="ticket.state === 'PROCESSING'">
            <img class="ico" src="../lib/images/incrase.png" title="Change to processing"> &nbsp;
        </a>
        <span ng-show="ticket.state === 'PROCESSING'">
            <img class="ico" src="../lib/images/incraseDisabled.png" title="Already processing"> &nbsp;
        </span>
        <a href="#">
            <img class="ico" src="../lib/images/approve.png" title="Satisfy ticket">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT 1**
Controller code added bellow.

```
angular.module('app').controller('TicketController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.tickets = [];

    /**
     * Get tickets.
     */
    $http.get('rest/tickets').then(function (response) {
        $scope.tickets = response.data;
    });

    /**
     * Create a ticket.
     */
    $scope.createTicket = function () {
        console.log('submit');
        $http({
            url: 'rest/tickets',
            method: "POST",
            data: $scope.ticket
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.tickets.push(response.data);
        }, function () {
            alert('Error: New ticket was not created.');
        }).finally(function () {
            $scope.ticket = {
                state: 'NEW'
            };
        })
    };

    /**
     * Reject a ticket.
     */
    $scope.rejectTicket = function (ticketId) {
        console.log('submit');
        $http({
            url: 'rest/tickets/reject',
            method: "PUT",
            data: ticketId
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.tickets.push(response.data);
        }, function () {
            alert('Error: Can not reject this ticket.');
        }).finally(function () {
            $scope.ticket = {};
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: Post your controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the {{}} notation in ngClick so this line:
     `<a href="#" ng-click="rejectTicket({{ticket.id}})">`
should be changed to:
     `<a href="#" ng-click="rejectTicket(ticket.id)">`